# Variation of Generalized singular value decomposition with more than two matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

I am familiar with the Generalized singular value decomposition (GSVD). In GSVD, given matrices $A_1 \in \mathbb{C}^{m_1 \times n}$ and $A_2 \in \mathbb{C}^{m_2 \times n}$ it is possible to decompose the two matrices such that
\begin{align*}
A_1 &= U_1 \Sigma_1 Q^H, \\
A_2 &= U_2 \Sigma_2 Q^H.
\end{align*}
Is it possible to generalize further with $M$ matrices? i.e. given $A_i$, $i \in 1, 2, \cdots, M$, decompose such that:
\begin{align*}
A_1 &= U_1 \Sigma_1 Q^H, \\
A_2 &= U_2 \Sigma_2 Q^H, \\
& \vdots \\
A_M &= U_M \Sigma_M Q^H.
\end{align*}

I have done a few web and Google Scholar searches, but I may be using the wrong keywords.

Bonus points if you can recommend a way to do this using Python. :)